# jQuery validation issue in tabbed page

Tags: jquery

I have a page with 4 jQuery tabs containing a different form on each tab.
Each form is supposed to take numbers that **cannot be > 100.**

I wrote this jQuery code to validate the form to make sure the number entered is < 100:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    var preventSubmit = 0;
    $('#targetForm').submit(function(){
        $(':input', '#targetForm').each(function(){
            if(this.value > 100){
                $('#message').fadeIn();
                $('#message').fadeOut(4000);
                prevent = 1;

            }//END IF

        });
        if(preventSubmit == 1){
            preventSubmit = 0;
            return false;
        }//END IF
    });
});
```

It works fine but only with the form on the first tab. If I click on the second tab and submit invalid data (over 100) it doesn't validate.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: If you're dynamically creating a new form after clicking on the second tab, you need to be sure to attach the `submit()` handler to this new form.

Comment: Every time I click on a tab the same page is loaded but an id is passed on the url (pageName?id=2). On the top of the page I grab the content based on the url id. So, it's basically the same page being redrawn with fresh content. I don't know how to attach the submit() handler since the jQuery code is on the form page. Thanks

Comment: Do you have multiple forms with the same `id`?

Comment: Each tab contains one form and yes, they've got the same id because I'm only loading fresh questions in the form and not the form tag itself.

Comment: If you try putting `alert('Test');` right below `$('#targetForm').submit(function() {`, then click on a tab and submit the new form, do you still get the alert? If not, then you need to re-attach the submit event handler.

Comment: Only get the alert on the first tab. I think I see what you're saying. It isn't working because of all forms have the same id? How am I going to re-attach the submit event handler if the form tag doesn't change? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you click on each tab and your AJAX request has finished modifying the form, be sure to re-attach your [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler to the form by calling:

```
$('#targetForm').submit(function() {
  $(':input', '#targetForm').each(function() {
    if (this.value > 100) {
      $('#message').fadeIn();
      $('#message').fadeOut(4000);
        prevent = 1;
    }
  });

  if (preventSubmit == 1) {
    preventSubmit = 0;
    return false;
  }
});
```

Assuming this is global Javascript, it is only ever run **once** when the page initially loads. It is not run again when AJAX requests get sent out and modify the form on the same page. Thus you need to call this function **again** after your AJAX request returns to ensure it is present on the newly modified form.

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding what you mean by re-attaching submit handler. The page is the same. The jQuery code is on the bottom of the page. So, everytime a new tab is clicked and a new form is loaded, the jQuery code is also loaded. So, I don't know how to re-attach it if the code is already on the page.

Comment: @user2160174 - When you click the tab, is it sending out an AJAX request (e.g. staying on the same page, but form elements are being **replaced**) or is it opening a completely separate page (even if that page has the same URL)? If you are using AJAX and staying on the same page, then removing any existing submit button may have removed the [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler from the form.

Comment: same page, only replacing form content.

Comment: @user2160174 - Not a problem. Happy to help :)